# I have a double while loop, and it does not seem to be working because of some logic I'm doing incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a double while loop, and it does not seem to be working because of some logic I'm doing incorrectly. I'm not sure what is wrong exactly, but I feel the code may be too complicated and somewhere, there is an error.

```
enter code here
 import math
 print("How many numbers am I estimating John?")
 count = int(input("COUNT> "))
 print("Input each number to estimate.")
 better_guess = 0
 initial_guess = 10
 i = 0
 j = 0
 t = 1
 list = []
 for j in range(count):
   num = float(input("NUMBER> "))
   list.append(num)
   j = j + 1
   if j == count:
     print("The square roots are as follows:")
 while i <= len(list):
   while t != 0 :
     initial_guess = 10
     better_guess = (initial_guess + (list[i])/initial_guess) / 2
     if initial_guess == better_guess:
      print(f"OUTPUT After {t} iterations, {list[i]}^0.5 = {better_guess}")
      i = i + 1
      break
    initial_guess = better_guess
   i = i + 1
```

Comment: What is the error and the intended behavior of your program?

Comment: do you need to indent the while loop to be inside the scope of the `if j ==` bit?

Comment: The intended behavior is to print the square roots which is given by the equation set to better_guess after a number of iterations. This code should be print every time :    if initial_guess == better_guess:
      print(f"OUTPUT After {t} iterations, {list[i]}^0.5 = {better_guess}")
      i = i + 1

Answer (score 0):

@viggnah is right, and I just ignored the num of iterations. But I think @viggnah 's num of iterations are 1 bigger than the actual num of iterations. E.g., if input is 4 and initial guess is 2, the iteration should be 0 rather than 1. Also I add `except` in case of illegal input.

I suppose the following code works as you expect.

```
import math
print("How many numbers am I estimating John?")
count = int(input("COUNT> "))
print("Input each number to estimate.")
better_guess = 0
initial_guess = 10
i = 0
j = 0
t = 1
list = []
while True:
    try:
        num = float(input("NUMBER> "))
        list.append(num)
        j = j + 1
        if j == count:
            print("The square roots are as follows:")
            break
    except:
        print("Invalid input! Try again.")
while i < len(list):
    initial_guess = 10
    t = 0
    while True:
        better_guess = (initial_guess + (list[i])/initial_guess) / 2
        if initial_guess == better_guess:
            print(f"OUTPUT After {t} iterations, {list[i]}^0.5 = {better_guess}")
            break
        t = t + 1
        initial_guess = better_guess
    i = i + 1
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

You need to understand:

1. We only need initialize guess once for each number. So do it in the first while loop;
2. `t`needs to be updated when initial_guess==better_guess rather than i, I believe this is a clerical error;
3. `initial_guess`needs to be updated in the second loop;

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code, @x pie has pointed out some of them but not all. The most important is that you are need to initalize `t` for every number in the list, so you can get the iterations for the numbers separately. Also, t needs to be incremented in the `while` loop, not inside the `if` block.

You can also clean up the code considerably, for example the `j` variable is not being used, list comprehension can be used to shorten the code (pythonic way), and iterating over lists can be done with `for num in list`.

Putting this altogether produces this:

```py
count = int(input('How many numbers am I estimating John? \nCOUNT> '))
print("Input each number to estimate.")
list = [float(input(f'NUMBER {i+1}> ')) for i in range(count)]
print("The square roots are as follows:")

for num in list:
    initial_guess = 10
    t = 0
    while True:
        better_guess = (initial_guess + num/initial_guess) / 2
        t += 1
        if initial_guess == better_guess:
            print(f"OUTPUT After {t} iterations, {num}^0.5 = {better_guess}")
            break
        initial_guess = better_guess
```

Sample run:

```
How many numbers am I estimating John? 
COUNT> 4
Input each number to estimate.
NUMBER 1> 1
NUMBER 2> 9
NUMBER 3> 16
NUMBER 4> 4
The square roots are as follows:
OUTPUT After 9 iterations, 1.0^0.5 = 1.0
OUTPUT After 7 iterations, 9.0^0.5 = 3.0
OUTPUT After 7 iterations, 16.0^0.5 = 4.0
OUTPUT After 8 iterations, 4.0^0.5 = 2.0
```